# Create "Landscape" Layout For Use in Portrait Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

I have a requirement to build a layout in "landscape" mode but used in an Activity that is locked in portrait mode.

The views in this layout (text, image, etc.) need to display inside of a card view so the user would have to rotate the phone in order to read it. In other words, the views would have to be set 90 degrees.

I have tried searching for examples and I am having a hard time because all the results end up being related to landscape orientation changes which isn't the problem I am trying to solve. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: you can build your layout as usual just set top as your start and your bot as end

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:rotation="90"` attribute on each of your child views.